# How to correctly show @2x retina images

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, retina-display

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2, the app is targeting iOS 6.0.
In my application, I am having trouble with showing iPad Retina images. I know I have to use the @2x~ipad.png extension in order to get them to properly show and I do that. My images are named according so they are all named the same besides the extension for each device.
Here is how I named it.

[image]

However,

```
 NSString *name=@"appearanceConnection.png";
 //NSString *name=@"appearanceConnection"; //I did check this
 //I did check the target
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
 NSLog(@"%f",image.size.width);
```

shows me the width of @1x image.

If i try to set proper image name manually:

```
  if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
            ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
            // Retina display
            name=@"appearanceConnection@2x~ipad.png";

            NSLog(@"retina");
        }
        else
        {
            name=@"appearanceConnection.png";
            NSLog(@"non-retina");
        }
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
     NSLog(@"%f",image.size.width);
```

proper @2x picked and then it scaled by 2.0 when I'm adding it to view.

I cleaned/rebuild my project many times, I reset IOS simulator settings, no result.
What am I doing wrong?

**update:**
non-retina

[image]

retina:

```
NSLog(@"%f", image.scale)
```

after `imageNamed` method gives me 1.0

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm trying to optimize my animation appearance, so I want to load one big image once and cut it by frames.
Firstly, I load big image (@2x or 1@x), then using cycle

```
for (int i = 0; i<numberOfFrames; i++)
    {
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage,
                                                           CGRectMake(i*width, 0.0f, width, height));
        UIImage *animationImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

        if (isFlip)
        {
            [animationImages insertObject:animationImage atIndex:0];
        }
        else
        {
            [animationImages addObject:animationImage];
        }

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    }
```

i cut this big image and create animation.
width and height are multiplied by 2 if it is retina display.

Maybe here is a caveat?

`UIImage *animationImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];`

returns me image scaled twice?

however, if I scale (0.5,0.5) UIImageView which is initialized by this image it fits. Have any idea why scaled twice?

Answer (score 3):

the retina and non retina images will have the same width and height when used as a UIImage or something similar, think of it as on retina displays the DPI of the image is doubled, and not the width or height.

this is to keep things transparent when coding for retina and non retina.

Comment: You can check the [scale](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW39) property on [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see if the system loaded the retina version.

Comment: Got you. I used incorrect terms. When I build my project within non-retina simulator everything is ok, within retina-display some views are too big and I do not get appropriate organization of my views.

Comment: ah, maybe change `name=@"appearanceConnection@2x~ipad.png";` to just `name=@"appearanceConnection.png";` i dont think you are meant to specify the 'size' of the image to load, it will choose the correct one for you

Comment: oh wait, you were just experimenting with that code, hmm that is odd why it doesnt load the right one then.. or are you? the images should look the same on retina and non retina (besides dpi difference), width and height should be the same too.. use the code in the first block you posted and check the scale property and see if it changes between retina and non retina

Comment: @Fonix, look, please, at my screenshot results.

Comment: you probably shouldnt be multiplying width and height by 2 when you are creating the CGRect for the image. that width and height is based off screen coordinates, which also dont scale up depending on retina/non-retina.

Comment: if i do not multiply, it cuts exactly by half. Just tried again. Scale property of animationImage is 1.0 too.

Comment: unfortunately i have run out of ideas, but something seems fishy if the width and height * 2 = 2, then width and height * 1 = 1/2 ...